# Toggle an element, display the others

Tags: jquery

Each time I select an option, it displays the list I wanted to but without hiding the others. Do I forgot something with the toggle function?

```
$("select#category").change(function() {
   var category = $(this).val();
   $("select#"+category).toggle();
});
```

My lists are as simple as that (must display either the "1" select or the "2" but not the two):

```
  <form method="post">
    <select name="menu_destination" id="category">
         <option value="1" >1</option>
         <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>

    <select name="menu_destination" id="1">
         <option value="a" >A</option>
         <option value="b">B</option>
    </select>

    <select name="menu_destination" id="2">
         <option value="a" >A</option>
         <option value="b">B</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without seeing your HTML, I'd suggest using `siblings()`. If this doesn't work, post your HTML for a more accurate solution.

```
$('#' + category).show().siblings().hide();
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/JgFmY/

P.S. You should use `$('#whatever')` vs `$('select#whatever')`. Unlike CSS, the first one is much faster in JQuery because it uses ECMAScript's native `getElementById()` function whereas the latter requires the use of sizzle. Since each DOM node should have a unique ID anyway, there's no need for the tag name prefix.

Comment: I've edited my first post. by the way your advice about ECMAScript is very useful, thanks

Comment: @Anon simply wrap #1 and #2 together in a div like my example and it will work. Point being you don't want #category to be a sibling of #1 and #2 or it will be hidden :)